# regex find specific tables in html

Tags: php, regex

i have html like bottom of this. and using PHP

```
<table style="...">
<tbody>
<tr> <img id="foo" src="foo"/></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> ....</p>
<table style="...">
<tbody>
<tr> <img id="bar" src="bar"/></tr
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm beginning PHP.
I want to find specific table like img src or id equals `foo` or `bar`.
but selected both tables.
here is my regex 
1.find tables has img tag

```
    /<table.*?>.*?<img *.*?<\/table>/
```

-> selected 2 table

2.add img src

```
<table.*?<img.+(src=.*?foo).*?<\/table>
```

-> selected all, from first  tag to last  tag

3.so try to not include `</table>` between ... tag.

```
<table.*?(?!<\/table>).*?<img.+(src=.*?foo).*?<\/table>
```

-> same result
I don't know what is wrong!
I was solved using preg_match_all() but still want know preg_match()
has any idea??

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This job is much better suited to using PHPs [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) classes. In this case we use an xpath to search for a `table` which has a descendant which is an `img` with it's `src` attribute equal to either `'foo'` or `'bar'`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$footable = $xpath->query("//table[descendant::img[@src='foo']]");
echo $footable->item(0)->C14N() . "\n";
$bartable = $xpath->query("//table[descendant::img[@src='bar']]");
echo $bartable->item(0)->C14N() . "\n";
```

Output:

```
<table style="..."><tbody><tr><img id="foo" src="foo"></img></tr></tbody></table>
<table style="..."><tbody><tr><img id="bar" src="bar"></img></tr></tbody></table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EBZN0)

Comment: i think $footable->C14N() is available php7.  i used php 5.4 so in my case try $footable->item(index)->C14N();

Comment: @SeonsooPark sorry about that - I keep forgetting not everyone uses PHP7 yet. I've updated my answer and demo link with code that will work on older versions as well.